# All Gmail IMAP messages go to Junk folder in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail, spam-prevention

All mails I receive in Gmail are received fine. When I ask Outlook to send and receive, I receive the mails in question – and they all go to Outlook's Junk mail folder.

They are totally removed from my Gmail account.

I have no Junk mail filters used in Outlook. Sending from Outlook works normally. What is wrong?

Comment: Outlook does not have a spam feature installed by default.  So something you have installed that interacts with Outlook is causing this.  I and millions of others do not have this problem.

Comment: Is it all your incoming emails or specific emails coming from a contact form? If it's emails coming from a contact form it could be a problem with how the headers are being generated in the email.

Comment: It is all mails, not any specific senders. I have an other computer with outlook 2010 and I have no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Outlook 2007.

I spent nearly 2 weeks trying all sorts of remedies I read about on the web.
There are multiple causes that can show these same symptoms, so it is hard to know what is causing it.

- I tried creating a new .pst file for my inbox
- Checking for a "Rule" (in Outlook, Tools > Rules and Alerts) that tells all mail to go into Junk.
- I created a new Profile.
- Thinking it might have been caused by a Microsoft Security upgrade, I restored back to my oldest backed up configuration using Windows Restore (which actually caused more problems).

You could try all these things.
None of them worked for me, however.

Eventually I realised that my antivirus program was not working properly (Norton in my case) I got Norton Support (Symantec own Norton) to uninstall and reinstall it and that fixed the problem with all my inbox mail going into the Junk.

I believe that Norton must have a default that if it cannot verify mail as "clean" it diverts it to the Junk folder. Since Norton was not working correctly it was failing all my mail messages, but the Norton Outlook extension that drops unvalidated mail into the Junk folder was still working.

That is my surmise.

Note: I use popmail not IMAP, but I doubt if that makes a significant difference in this particular case.

Good luck, 
Jon